# Is it possible to use x:bind style binding inside a page's resource dictionary?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, resourcedictionary, ivalueconverter, xbind

I have the following scenario ...

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:EnumToBoolean x:Key="Empty" Expected="Empty"/>
    <converters:EnumToBoolean x:Key="Full"  Expected="Full"/>
</Page.Resources>

.
.
.

<SomeControl IsChecked="{x:Bind ViewModel.State, Converter={StaticResource Empty}, Mode=TwoWay}"/> 
<SomeControl IsChecked="{x:Bind ViewModel.State, Converter={StaticResource Full},  Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

`EnumToBoolean` is an `IValueConverter` that converts a c# `enum` into a `boolean`.

It uses the `Expected` value to determine if `ViewModel.State` is true or false. This is the `Convert` part of `IValueConverter` and it works, nothing special.

However, the `ConvertBack` needs the original value of `ViewModel.State` to return as the result, if the 'boolean' value is false. Returning a 'null' as expected causes a runtime exception.

I Tried two approaches to get the `Original` value to the `ConvertBack` function of the converter:

a) added another field `Original` and attempted to bind it

```
<converters:EnumToBoolean x:Key="Empty" Expected="Empty" Original="{x:Bind ViewModel.State, Mode=OneWay}"/>
<converters:EnumToBoolean x:Key="Full"  Expected="Full"  Original="{x:Bind ViewModel.State, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

*this compiles and runs, but causes a run-time exception; because it tries to bind to the converter before the converter is instantiated*

b) attempted to pass it as a `ConverterParameter` with an embedded binding

```
<SomeControl IsChecked="{x:Bind ViewModel.State, Converter={StaticResource Empty}, ConverterParameter={x:Bind ViewModel.WallPainter, Mode=OneWay}, Mode=TwoWay}"/> 
<SomeControl IsChecked="{x:Bind ViewModel.State, Converter={StaticResource Full},  ConverterParameter={x:Bind ViewModel.WallPainter, Mode=OneWay}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

*this does not compile at all; it fails with a non-descriptive error without an error code or any hits here or on google ... "**Event values cannot be broken across a line boundary**"*

does anyone have a suggestion of how to get either of these scenarios working?

**NOTE** - *my temporary solution, far from ideal, is to make the* `Original` *field of the converter* `public Func<TEnum> Original { get; set; }` *and set its getter* `function` *in code behind. I do not care for this option as it fragments binding implementation strategies.*

Comment: I think your question title is a little missleading, as this isn't really a binding issue. Value Converters are designed to do one to one conversions. Could you add your converter code ore make a little clearer what it is intended to do?

Comment: I can't very understand your problem, in `ConvertBack`, if the value is true, you want to keep the `ViewModel.State` to its original value, and if the value is false, return a null value to clear the value of `ViewModel.State` ?